# Easiest singer Rebus.. Give it a try?

Tags: rebus

Easiest singer rebus[image]

Who is the singer?

Comment: Is this even supposed to be a `rebus` because it's more of a graffitti!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The singer is:

> Eminem

because:

> he plays Jimmy "B-Rabbit" Smith Jr in the movie [8 mile](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298203/).
>  B-Rabbit is written(graffitied) in the given picture.

Comment: Can i know what are the downvotes for?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the people that did just blindly based their opinions on ABcDexter's comment. People sometimes just blindly follow like that. But the word in the rebus is not the answer, even though it's very easy to find the answer, you did make that clear in the title. So I think it is a rebus, people like ABcDexter just criticize it because it's not how they would have done it.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of "i wouldve done it differently" i didnt dv... But to me this isn't a puzzle. It's just a "can you read this graffiti and happen to know 8 miles" which...doesnt make it a puzzle (to me at least)